# SQL Check from multiple tables if datetime is within 48 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT t.contact_name as contact_name, t.contact_email as contact_email,
    t.ticketnumber as ticketnumber, t.subject as subject
FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates tu ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber
WHERE tu.type = 'update' AND
    t.status = 'Awaiting Customer' AND
    tu.datetime <= '2014-10-27 11:18:19'
GROUP BY tu.ticketnumber
order by tu.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

which should shows records from `tickets` when the latest row in `ticket_updates` is more than 48 hours ago

i want to be able to automatically change the `status` in `tickets` if there has been nothing added in `ticket_updates` within 48 hours

in `ticket_updates` I have 3 rows with the following datetime:

```
2014-11-22 00:00:00
2014-10-26 00:00:00
2014-10-28 00:00:00
```

so the last one is within 48 hours but its showing a result on the above query when it shouldn't

Comment: Is this really necessary? `SELECT t.*, tu.*`?

Comment: no, i meant to take that out before i posted. i have removed this from my code anyway (not that it makes a difference)

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY clause is frequently inapproriate and potentially misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with inner select (*not tested*):

```
SELECT t.contact_name as contact_name,
       t.contact_email as contact_email,
       t.ticketnumber as ticketnumber,
       t.subject as subject
FROM tickets t
JOIN ticket_updates tu ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber
WHERE t.status = 'Awaiting Customer'
AND t.ticketnumber NOT IN
    (
    -- returns ticketnumbers that have recent updates
    SELECT recentUpdates.ticketnumber
    FROM ticket_updates recentUpdates
    WHERE recentUpdates.type = 'update' AND recentUpdates.datetime => '2014-10-27 11:18:19'
    )
GROUP BY tu.ticketnumber
ORDER BY tu.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're joining on all ticket updates then dropping the ones from the last 48 hours. you want to use the latest update as a condition of the join.

try replacing your join with this.

```
   join (select Max (tu.datetime), tu.ticketnumber from ticket_updates tu
    group by tu.ticketnumber) tu 
    on tu.t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber
```